# Complex integration exercise

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

I have to calculate $$\int_0^{2\pi}\arctan \biggl( \frac{\sin \theta} {\cos \theta +3}\biggr)d\theta$$ I don't have any ideas, but I think that I should apply a substitution. Can you give me a hint? Thank you in advance

Comment: Make the substitution $z=e^{i\theta }$ and use residue theorem.

Comment: Are you able to find the poles of the integrand?  Particularly those with real part between $0$ and $2\pi$?  Are you able to find their residues?

Comment: Thank you, I made that substitution, and I obtained $\oint_C \frac {\arctan \frac {z^2-1}{iz^2+3iz+i}}{zi}dz$. However this implies that the integral is equal to $2\pi \arctan i $. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Show that the integral is equal to
$$\operatorname {Im} \int_{|z - 3| = 1} \frac {i \ln z} {3 - z} dz$$
with a suitable choice of $\ln z$. $z = 0$ is not a pole for the integrand that you've obtained ($3 i z$ should be $6 i z$, but $z = 0$ still would be a branch point).

Comment: Note
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\arctan  \frac{\sin \theta} {3+\cos \theta } d\theta \overset{\theta \to \pi +\theta}=
-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\arctan  \frac{\sin \theta} {3-\cos \theta } d\theta =0
$$
due to odd integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\arctan\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta + 3}\right)=\text{Im}\log\left(i\sin\theta+\cos\theta+3\right)=\text{Im}\log(3+e^{i\theta})=\text{Im}\log\left(1+\frac{e^{i\theta}}{3}\right) $$
so the integral equals
$$ \text{Im}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{e^{ni\theta}}{n 3^n}\,d\theta=\text{Im}(0)=\color{red}{0}.$$

Comment: Sorry if I comment now, I don't understand how to justify the first equality that you wrote. Can you explain to me where does it come from? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

oops, I missed the part it should be done by complex integration...
Anyway, I'll leave this result as a hint what to look for.
Note that
$$
\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(\pi-x)}{3+\cos(\pi-x)}\right) =
\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{3-\cos(x)}\right)
$$
and
$$
\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(\pi+x)}{3+\cos(\pi+x)}\right) =
-\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{3-\cos(x)}\right)
$$
thus integration from $0$ to $2\pi$ yields $0$.